# Square sheet in middle layers

Tags: sla, dlp, resin

I'm using a Tronxy Ultrabot (looks very similar to Anycubic Photon) and I'm still on my first prints.
Things that happened thus far: many failed prints that stuck to the resin tank, one which I had to carefully scoop off.

What I'm finding odd is that this sheet (for lack of a better term) only seems to happen on one half of the whole thing.

I'm suspecting the FEP film is the culprit here, due to earlier failures.

What else could be causing this error?
Other info that might be important, the model is using 6 layer, 60s cure time for base; 0.04mm layer size, 10s layer cure time, 1s delay between layers. The resin is [Suen Ching](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33025328151.html)

Edit 2: [Here's the manual](https://srv-file2.gofile.io/download/Tekehz/UltraBot%20User%20Manual.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Hi, please provide a link to your printer model - or better yet the User Manual.  That will help people understand what is supposed to happen (illumination method, e.g.) . In general, a problem on half the build plate suggests improper levelling, but I am not familiar with your printer.

Comment: The model is this one
https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32843892253.html ; i'm looking for the user manual, but i can't seem to find it online. It's in terrible english, but I can scan it later if needed

Comment: not an answer to your question but your print looks over exposed, you many want to try shorter than 10s for your layer exposer time.

Comment: what software are you using as your slicer?

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess but it may be a problem with the sliced file. Take a look though the layers of the sliced file to see if your software is adding a layer there. sometimes it looks fine in the 3d model but it can add a layer while slicing.

Comment: The problem were the models themselves. I had to run them through Windows 3D Builder to fix whatever invisible problems the slicer would transform into faces.

Comment: @Arthur if this answer worked for you you should mark it as accepted so others know you are not still looking for an answer.